# How to understand ANTLRWorks 1.5.2 MismatchedTokenException(80!=21)

Tags: parsing, antlr3

I'm testing a simple grammar (shown below) with simple input strings and get the following error message from the Antlrworks interpreter: `MismatchedTokenException(80!=21).`

My input `(abc45{r24})` means "repeat the keys a, b, c, 4 and 5, 24 times."

```
ANTLRWorks 1.5.2 Grammar:
expr        : '(' (key)+ repcount ')' EOF;
key         : KEY | digit ;
repcount    : '{' 'r' count '}';
count       : (digit)+;
digit       : DIGIT;

DIGIT   :   '0'..'9';
KEY     :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ;

Inputs:
(abc4{r4}) - ok
(abc44{r4}) - fails NoViableAltException
(abc4 4{r4}) - ok
(abc4{r45}) - fails MismatchedTokenException(80!=21)
(abc4{r4 5}) - ok
```

The parse succeeds with input `(abc4{r4})` (single digits only).
The parse fails with input `(abc44{r4})` (NoViableAltException).
The parse fails with input `(abc4{r45})` (MismatchedTokenException(80!=21)).
The parse errors go away if I put a space between 44 or 45 to separate the individual digits.

Q1. What does NoViableAltException mean? How can I interpret it to look for a problem in the grammar/input pair?

Q2. What does the expression `80!=21` mean? Can I do anything useful with the information to look for a problem in the grammar/input pair?

I don't understand why the grammar has a problem reading successive digits. I thought my expressions `(key)+` and `(digit)+` specify that successive digits are allowed and would be read as successive individual digits.

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, I would be grateful. This seems like a simple problem, but hours later, I still don't understand why and how to solve it. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Further down in my simple grammar file I had a lexer rule for FLOAT copied from another grammar. I did not think to include it above (or check it as a source of the errors) because it was not used by any parser rule and would never match my input characters. Here is the FLOAT grammar rule (which contains sequences of DIGITs):

```
FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;
```

If I delete the whole rule, all my test cases above parse successfully. If I leave any one of the three FLOAT clauses in the grammar/lexer file, the parses fail as shown above.

Q3. Why does the FLOAT rule cause failures in the parse? The DIGIT lexer rule appears first, and so should "win" and be used in preference to the FLOAT rule. Besides, the FLOAT rule doesn't match the input stream.

I hazard a guess that the lexer is skipping the DIGIT rule getting stuck in the FLOAT rule, even though FLOAT comes after DIGIT in the input file.

SCREENSHOTS

I took these two screenshots after Bart's comment below to show the parse failures that I am experiencing. Not that it matters, but ANTLRWorks 1.5.2 will not accept the syntax `SPACE : [ \t\r\n]+;` regular expression syntax in Bart's kind replies. Maybe the screenshots will help. They show *all* the rules in my grammar file.

The only difference in the two screenshots is that one input has two sets of multiple digits and the other input string has only set of multiple digits. Maybe this extra info will help somehow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You tagged your question as `antlr4`, but I now see you're using v3. There are small differences in how ANTLR4 and v3 handle some lexer matching. I don't have v3 installed/operational to check this, alas.My suggestion is to move away from v3 since it is rather old, and v4 is much more powerful.

Comment: Added an answer that might explain what you see. Best of luck @Kevin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, ANTLR's v3 lexer is less powerful than v4's version. When the lexer gets the input `"123x"`, this first 3 chars (`123`) are consumed by the lexer rule `FLOAT`, but after that, when the lexer encounters the `x`, it knows it cannot complete the `FLOAT` rule. However, the v3 lexer does not give up on its partial match and tries to find another rule, below it, that matches these 3 chars (`123`). Since there is no such rule, the lexer throws an exception. Again, not 100% sure, this is how I remember it.

ANTLRv4's lexer ***will*** give up on the partial `123` match and will return `23` to the char stream to create a single `KEY` token for the input `1`.

I highly suggest you move away from v3 and opt for the more powerful v4 version.

Comment: Hi Bart, I started out with v4, and want to use v4 (thus the ANTLR4 tag). But the tool I found (Antlrworks 1.5.2) was so convenient that I thought I would debug the grammar in v3 and then move the grammar to v4. Antlrworks 2 is nothing like Antlrworks 1.5.2. I don't have Eclipse installed and don't understand Java very well. Do you know of a tool like (A 1.5.2) that is convenient for debugging grammars? I would gladly move to v4 for debugging, but couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: I've also used Eclipse, but I find IntelliJ the superior IDE. It als has a free community edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download And then install the ANTLR4 plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4-grammar-plugin . A more light-weight solution would be to use Visual Studio Code + the plugin for ANTLR (never used it, but also looks great: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4 )

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will investigate those environments and see what my grammar produces. I wish there was a good plugin for Visual Studio C#. The ability to (visually) debug grammars like Antlrworks 1.5.2 does seems extremely helpful to me. I'll have to see what the other environments provide. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi Bart, I tried out IntelliJ+Antlr plugin (thank you for the links!). After hunting around for a while, I was able to cut/paste my grammar into a scratch file and test it. It worked fine, just as you said. Is there any way to change the starting rule in IntelliJ/Antlr? Is there any way to save the grammar file to a folder of my choice instead of Roaming? (I looked for menu choices and help on those two things, but found nothing. IntelliJ is powerful, but I couldn't find a SaveAs option to save my scratch grammar to an arbitrary path.)

Comment: I just tried out your suggested Visual Studio Code + Antlr4 plugin! Wow! After figuring out a pile of nuances on how to operate VSCode and launch configurations, I got my little grammar running - the VSC+Antlr implementation is beautiful. I'm off to the races now. THANK YOU again for your newbie help. Your help made all the difference.